# How to get UserSettingName.GroupingInformation without using Autodiscover in Exchange?

Tags: c#, exchange-server

By using Exchange Autodiscover feature I can get user settings including GroupingInformation which is required to batch streaming notifications.

If I know Exchange server url is there a way to get GroupingInformation without using Autodiscover?

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to use AutoDiscover to get the grouping information.  However, you can cache the AutoDiscover response for up to 24 hours and re-AutoDiscover every 24 hours if you get an error with Streaming Notifications before that.

Comment: Can you please explain what is the nature of this "User Settings". I mean if there's a user it's connected to some Exchange server and it's settings stored there. Why I can't retrieve them with some request? I know it's not documented anywhere, but why "Autodiscover" is the only way to get them? Just curious.